# Flutter Stream Builder to a single Document

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

**How can I access the snapshot data?**

I have followed the method described [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/) to cast it to <Map<String, dynamic>> as described here but it returns null;

**Another exception was thrown: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in typecast**

```
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // It provide us total height and width
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: db.collection('products').doc(widget.product.uid).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white)),
            );
          } else {
            print(snapshot.data?.data());
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                snapshot.data?.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            print(data);
            return Container(child: Text(data['name']));
          }
        });
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update this:

```
 Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data?.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

to:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

**Explanation:**

What the new code does is to cast the type of `snapshot.data` from [Map<String, dynamic>](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) [?](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/data.html) to `Map<String, dynamic>` by using the bang operator (the exclamation mark) which does the following:

> A postfix exclamation mark (!) takes the expression on the left and
> casts it to its underlying non-nullable type.

When you used the question mark after `snapshot.data`, that meant it could return `null` if `snapshot.data` is `null` and `Null` can't be cast to `Map<String, dynamic>`. That explains the error message.

Since you already have this check: `if (!snapshot.hasData) {}`, it's safe to use the bang operator on `snapshot.data` in the else block.

https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html